# Anyway to capture form data via POST method on Android WebView?

Tags: android, post, webview, capture, intercept

This question has been brought up a ton, but I have not found a clear answer.  I'd rather not take the JS injection approach, because I feel that I should not have to...

Basically what I'm doing is making an Android application that will act as an offline counterpart to a web site.  When synced up, it will pull any changes to the sites html, JS, and CSS files if needed.  Then while offline, it will display that in the WebView.

I want to be able to pull data from the form as if it were online, but pull it from the WebView and save it into a DB on the device.  Then, when back online, the application will sync that data to the actual web site database.

I know how to get this to work with GET, but I'd much rather pull sensitive in with a POST.